# Pentaho : Images not having correct path

Tags: apache, pentaho

I am running Pentaho reports. The problem is all the images are set to localhost:8080 etc, so, I am not able to view the images. Can you tell me where this property be available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The related setting for that is called "base-url" in your web.xml file. Change this to a public IP or domain name. The base-url is used by all content-generators to create links to other files.

Make sure you only access the server via the public IP/name that has been configured there - otherwise you may run into troubles with the security layer as it relies on cookies to authenticate yourself and thus it may prevent you from seeing that content as you appear to be not logged in.

Comment: Thanks Thomas,  Can you please elaborate on the second point.

Comment: Cookies are sent based on the domain name. So if you access your pentaho-server as "www.myserver.example" but your report contains references as IP-address or as adress other than "www.myserver.example", your browser will NOT send the authentication cookie back and the server thinks you are a new user on a different session.